# How to investigate why my VIM freezing for 5 sec during saving Rails application files?

Tags: macos, vim, ruby-on-rails

What can cause an issue when I am saving a file in rails application folder freezing for about 5 seconds? How to investigate this issue?

**VIMRC**: https://gist.github.com/4632cbcfc655899c934f

Comment: Are the files saved locally, or to a network share? Do you have some kind of script/hook in place backing up files as they are saved?

Comment: locally of course, no I don't

Comment: Please don't post simultaneously to multiple Stack Overflow sites (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641939/what-can-cause-5-sec-delay-during-saving-file-in-vim), and if one answered your question, at least have the decency to delete the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps setting the '`verbose`' option to 15 or higher immediately before writing, and watching the output would give you some clue about where it is stalling. See:

```
:help 'verbose'
```

(With the single quotes as part of the command.)